# How to run React application by clicking index.html file without any local server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have created react application using create-react-app when I start "npm start" it is running using localhost:3000 in browser which is fine. But, when I click index.html from project folder it is showing blank page. Can you suggest me solutions on how to run react application using index.html file

Answer (score 6):

Add `"homepage": ".",` to the top of your `package.json` file. Then build with `yarn build` or `npm build`. Go to `build/` folder and double click on `index.html`.
[image]
[image]

EDIT:

> Opening the app via index.html needs `"homepage": "."` in `package.json` because without it Webpack tries to load the static files from the root the file system rather than build directory. [Reference](https://medium.com/@louis.raymond/why-cant-i-open-my-react-app-by-clicking-index-html-d1778f6324cf)

Comment: can you please share the details about   "homepage": ".",

Comment: @DeepKakkar I added an explanation in the answer. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `npm run build`, then go to the “build” folder where a working index.html will be located. The index.html in the project folder isn’t built for production/standalone use.